# Laravel angularjs cross origin session

Tags: angularjs, session, laravel, laravel-4, cross-domain

I have a problem with communication between angular and laravel.

Its about mobile application that needs to log in to a laravel framework and get some data.

Mobile application is angularjs based, and for login i user standard $httpd function.

Login works fine, and i get expected response from laravel, but when i make another request assuming that im loged in, laravel returns NULL for session and auth. When I upload mobile app to a server where laravel is installed all works like a charm. But my app needs to be on mobile device, so thats not a solution.

I assume that the problem is in cors or cross domain communication. It seems that laravel destroys session made from cross origin requests, because that session is not accessible from another request, and on another request laravel tries to make a new one.

I need help solving that session problem (access session after login or keep session), i hope some of you have some kind of a solution.

i tried :

- changing headers in my login controller
- changing get to post
- adding content type to my angular http req (Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
- tried requerst with jquery ajax
- changed laravels app/config/session.php values of driver, cookie, domain...
- setting vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/http/frameGuard.php x-frame options to false

no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json web tokens, and simply set it up so that you request a JWT on login, and you can share that token around - the only way it invalidates, is either if you lose the token, or it times out.

Comment: hm can you plese be more specific or just point me in right direction, I have never used web tokes? where to start?

Comment: Just google for json web tokens and you'll get a slew of articles and resources on what they are, how they're meant to function - then you can either implement your own to suit your requirements or find a library to suit your needs.

Admittedly, this is a pretty fresh approach and you NEED to have SSL enabled for your application, so if that doesn't fit, best off sticking to sessions (though good luck!) :)